# Convert html to string using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am getting the DOM using:

```
var cc = angular.element(document.querySelector('.abc'));
$scope.myEl = cc[0];
```

'.abc' is class of which I am getting the DOM. I want to convert this HTML DOM into string in Angularjs. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: cc.html(); to get the content as string

Comment: And to get the DOM, you can simply use: angular.element(".abc")[0]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)

Comment: @Vanojx1 Thanks, It worked!!!